# SQL table design for storing Nested arrays

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, sql-server, linq

I am trying to implement [Easy Form Builder](https://github.com/MacKentoch/easyFormGenerator)

using AngularJS and ASP.NET Web API, SQL 2012 for DB. I am confused about how to design the tables. Here's the Data Structure of a single field

```
   {
  "className": "row",
        "fieldGroup": [{
          "className": "col-xs-4",
          "type": "basicSelect",
          "key": "basicSelect-002",
          "templateOptions": {
            "type": "",
            "label": "Select City",
            "placeholder": "",
            "description": "Select City",
            "required": false,
            "options": [{
                "name": "Dhaka",
                "value": "0",
                "group": ""
              },
              {
                "name": "Rajshahi",
                "value": "1",
                "group": ""
              }
            ]
          }
        }]
      }
    }
```

Should I create 3 tables(ie. fields, templateOptions, options) and join when reading the data? If so, should I use stored procedure or linq?

How should I procede?

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Or, should I keep all of them in string? Would that create any complications in future?

Comment: Yoour input would be two rows in the database.  All the columns would be the same in the two rows except the options in yoiu use one table.  Another option would be to put the data into two tables.  The first table would contain all the columns except the options.  Then add options to 2nd table with the a unique key (like basicSelect-002) that can be used to Join the two tables.

Comment: Since you will always be reading the form as a single unit and unless you are doing some kind of processing on it (not likely), I would just store it as a blob (varchar(max)) and key field.  `Id int not null identity, Form varchar(max)`

Comment: Got it! I'll keep the key and label in different columns and the whole data in a varchar(max). Thanks @RobertMcKee

Comment: Keeping in two tables would have been a better idea if I needed all the data individually. Thanks @jdweng

Comment: Oh, another question! Should I keep all the data for all Forms in one table or dynamically create individual table for each forms?